# Bitmap access violation exception with camera image

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, camera, eventargs

In my WPF application images are taken with a camera use a view and then passed as bitmaps to another when it's closed via eventargs. However, when I then try to process the images I get the AccessViolationException. This does not occure when I process the images before they are passed or when I use images loaded from a file.

Getting the image from the camera (The `PtCamera` class is my wrapper for the `Camera` class from the API)

```
 Bitmap GetRefImage(PtCamera cam)
    {

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(2560, 1920, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        if (cam.IsConnected)
        {
           cam.FetchImage(out image);
        }
        else
        {
           ErrorOccurred?.Invoke(this, $"GetRefImage: {cam.Error}");
        }
        
        return image;
    }
```

In this context I can access the bitmap and process it as I like.

After passing the bitmap when the view is closed:

```
void CloseZoomedView(bool isConf)
    {
        if (cam is object && cam.IsConnected)
            cam.Close();
        ZoomClosingArgs eArg = new ZoomClosingArgs()
        {
            IsConfirmed = isConf,
            RefImage = refImage,
        };
        ClosingZoom?.Invoke(this, eArg);
    }
```

The exception occurs directly when accessing the data in the other viewmodel:

```
void HandleZoomImageClosed(object sender, ZoomClosingArgs e)
{
    if (e is object && e.IsConfirmed)
    {
        Color test = e.RefImage.GetPixel(0, 0);
        //...
    }
 }
```

The bitmap is generated by accessing the memory of the camera via `FetchImage()`

```
   public void FetchImage(out Bitmap image)
   {
      camera.Memory.GetActive(out int memID);
      camera.Memory.ToBitmap(memID, out image);
   }
```

If i replace the code in `FetchImage()` with just a new Bitmap from file

```
image = new Bitmap(@"d:\testimage.png")
```

It works without problems in any context.

The API documentation simply states the following:

> Accessible
>
> Camera.Memory.ToBitmap
>
> Syntax
>
> uEye.Memory.ToBitmap(int s32MemId, out System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
>
> Description
>
> Returns a bitmap which contains the image. The method uses the already
> allocated image memory and the image is displayed in the format you
> specified when allocating the image memory.

Any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: As a note, `public void FetchImage(out Bitmap image)` is kind of an odd API. You would typically declare the method as `public Bitmap FetchImage()` and return the Bitmap, as you do in `GetRefImage`. Note also that the initialization of the `bitmap` variable in GetRefImage is pointless. The initial Bitmap is never used.

Comment: @Clemens: Yeah, I adapted it for the post. Acutally, the   FetchImage() method returns a bool indicating wether the camera methods were returning the correct state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was closing my camera object too early. In `CloseZoomedView()` the `cam.Close()` method releases all the memory areas taken up by the camera. With passing a new Bitmap before closing it works like a charm.

```
void CloseZoomedView(bool isConf)
{        
     ZoomClosingArgs eArg = new ZoomClosingArgs()
     {
        IsConfirmed = isConf,
        RefImage = new Bitmap(refImage),
     };
     
     if (cam is object && cam.IsConnected)
        cam.Close();

     ClosingZoom?.Invoke(this, eArg);
 }
```